# What does a google cloud messaging registeration id looks like?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In internet I am seeing examples like they are simple indiced `("1", "2", "42" etc)` however gcm.register returns a very long string for me `("APA91bEf9sThIN9wagUAPTzn16igAFg_h7FxBKbKpzHgIJpDivY4RLWiVRpvIE1go7Lqi1jraVggKnXfzp1Owks5k7ZHgKnDNbj2pe2KkPyL5jn8a_8ApcpoRL.... like a hundred character)`

Is this supoosed to be happen? I can't send also send messages, I don't know if they are related

> curl -X POST -H "Authorization:key=AIzaSyBRjz...ArolkyANF-pMgJ8Kg" --data '{ "data": {   "score": "5x1",    "time": "15:10"  },
>   "registration_ids": [ "APA91bEf9sThIN9wagUAPTzn16igAFg_h7FxBKbKpzHgIJpDivY4RLWiVR...ECYYtiKQ3wq68PvuIj2OCaYQm5nzxrg" ] }' https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

gives me Error=MissingRegistration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the gcm reg id is like what you got. Error must be something else.

this is mine

reggg APA91bHgP3QU_v-z98i0KLk7Z2Svkxljnb5_R_7z4-  gEbIHs4nVWTF8dq3nwE6fJLBfxGvI3JiTWJOo9SVh6htYO7IBenspwQwePyOJWJsINTrTrlENP4AyE6c6AsQIeNnrYCiQ7C-B4

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I also fixed the issue, I wasn't adding content-type Content-Type:"application/json" to headers.